# Where does this derivative come from?

Tags: calculus

This an MIT exam problem:

A rocket has launched straight up, and its altitude is $\ h = 10t^2$
feet after t seconds.

You are on the ground 1000 feet from the launch site. The line
of sight from you to the rocket makes an angle θ with the horizontal. By how many
Radians per second is θ changing, 10 seconds after the launch?

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2E7k.png)

Where does this guy come from?

$$sec^2\theta\frac{d\theta}{dt} = \frac{t}{50}$$

I know the identity is

$$ sec^2\theta =\frac{d}{d\theta}tan\theta$$

and
$$ \frac{t}{50} = \frac{d}{d\theta}tan\theta$$

Why they add $\frac{d\theta}{dt}$ next to $sec^2\theta$

Comment: Chain rule. This is a related rates problem, so $\theta$ is a function of $t.$

Comment: So $sec^2\theta$ is the outer function and $\frac{d\theta}{dt}$ is the inner function?

Answer (score 1):

This is a related rates question, and the objective is to find and evaluate $\left.\frac{d\theta}{dt}\right\rvert_{t=10}$

From the context of the problem, we know

$tan{\theta} = \frac{h(t)}{1000} = \frac{t^2}{100}$

To find $\frac{d\theta}{dt}$, we differentiate implicitly by treating $\theta$ as a function of $t$. To implicitly differentiate $tan\theta$, we utilize the chain rule where $tan\theta$ is the outer function and $\theta(t)$ is the inner function. Consequently,

$[tan{\theta}]' = [\frac{t^2}{100}]'$ $\Rightarrow$ $\frac{d\theta}{dt}sec^2\theta = \frac{t}{50}$

Hence

$\frac{d\theta}{dt} = \frac{tcos^2\theta}{50}$

Completing the problem,

$tan\theta = \frac{h(10)}{1000} = 1$

$\Rightarrow \theta=arctan(1) = \frac{\pi}{4}$

Therefore,

$\left.\frac{d\theta}{dt}\right\rvert_{t=10} = \frac{cos^2(\frac{\pi}{4})}{5}$

$= \frac{1}{10}$ radians per second.